# What I have to put as the uri of my HttpGet method?

Tags: java, php, android, api, rest

I'm doing an API REST application in Android and I'm trying to get my `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` methods from my application in Android.

I saw that for that objective I have to use `HttpGet(String uri)` method but I'm not really secure about what `uri` I have to put. I saw the info here:

http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html#HttpGet(java.net.URI)

Have I put the `uri` of the folder in which my `api.php` file it's allocate? api.php it's the file in which I have GET, PUT, POST and DELETE method.

Have I put the `uri` that I set on my methods (GET/POST/PUT/DELETE) to make reference to the information that they retrieve to me?

I searched on the Internet but I couldn't find any that helps to me.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you should use full or relative path to you file. Your String uri will become new URI(uri, true, charset) in HttpMethodBase.

Comment: @varren Thank you man! But do I have to also call to `new URL` or it will be automaticaly?

Comment: no you can just put string in HttpGet(String uri) and HttpGet will do the job

Comment: @varren Thank you man! If you put it as an answer I will mark it as accept.

Answer (score 0):

The URI in your case would likely be the URL (often used interchangeably with URI) of the REST webservice endpoint (e.g. http://someserver/restService/users).

The constructor **HttpGet(String uri)** accepts a String as a parameter, so you can just stick the URL in there surrounded by double quotes:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://someserver/restService/users");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some explanation, because my comments are not really informative):

According to http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html path can be:

`GET http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1`

And it works fine in httpcomponents-client. 2-nd option is:

`GET /pub/WWW/TheProject.html HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3.org`

Should be fine if you set Host Header but for some reason httpcomponents-client will just throw org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException, so you need to set the default host name and below is fast code example of both options. Probably i'm missing some obvious way to set default Hostname. But the easiest way to go is just use full path to the file.

```
import org.apache.http.Header;
import org.apache.http.HttpException;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.HttpRequest;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoute;
import org.apache.http.conn.routing.HttpRoutePlanner;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultRoutePlanner;
import org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultSchemePortResolver;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // this works fine
        testAbsolutePath(); 

        // this throws org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
        // if you don't specify target Host. 
        // i'm setting HttpRoutePlanner on HttpClient in this example to do this
        testRelativePath(); 

    }
    public static void testAbsolutePath() throws Exception{
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        String absolutePath = "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30605198/what-i-have-to-put-as-the-uri-of-my-httpget-method";
        HttpGet absolutePathRequest = new HttpGet(absolutePath);
        testRequest(absolutePathRequest, client);
    }

    public static void testRelativePath() throws Exception{
        // the easiest way i could find to set default hostname for     
        // 'org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.6'
        HttpRoutePlanner rp = new DefaultRoutePlanner(DefaultSchemePortResolver.INSTANCE) {
            @Override
            public HttpRoute determineRoute(final HttpHost host,final HttpRequest request,final HttpContext context) throws HttpException {
                HttpHost target = host != null ? host : new HttpHost("www.stackoverflow.com");
                return super.determineRoute(target, request, context);
            }
        };

        HttpClient client =  HttpClientBuilder.create().setRoutePlanner(rp).build();
        String relativePath = "/questions/30605198/what-i-have-to-put-as-the-uri-of-my-httpget-method";
        HttpGet relativePathRequest = new HttpGet(relativePath);

        testRequest(relativePathRequest, client);
    }

    public static void testRequest(HttpGet request, HttpClient client) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(request);
        for (Header h : request.getAllHeaders()) System.out.println(h);
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = client.execute(request, responseHandler);
        System.out.println(responseBody.substring(0, 100)); //substring because don't want to print all page
    }
}
```

Comment: When I mean the route of my file I mean `C:/project/...` or should I have to use the url that I use to make reference to that `get` method: `localhost/project/...` in my browser? I also don't understand very well why you make this `ResponseHandler<String>`. Does it get the information in a String? Thank you again!

Comment: Yeah `ResponseHandler<String>` is just a fast way to get a string from the response (html page in my case, but can be some json or xml string, depending on the page.). I think yes, you will need some server running, because you don't need code from file api.php. You need it to be executed and give you some result data.  `http://localhost/project/...` or something like `http://localhost:8080/project/...`, depending on you server config. If it works in browser, then it is the url you need.

Comment: It is the same as `HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(method);String Str = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());`
            `JSONArray json = new JSONArray(Str);`?

Comment: Yep, it is doing exactly the same (if the response was successful (a 2xx status code) Here is source code: http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.ning/metrics.action/0.2.1/org/apache/http/impl/client/BasicResponseHandler.java

Comment: Thank you man and last question, if my `get` method has more than one values (I get the information from a database), are they one next to another one in the string? Are they separated by comas or spaces?

Comment: If i got your question right, you need to format your request url like this `PATH_TO_THE_API_FILE?name=Bob&age=50` and so on, using `&` as a separator

Comment: I mean that `ResponseHandler` returns a String. Is it, when I retrieve more than 1 different type of data, for example, int, string, long, etc..., all the data in the same String?

Comment: Ah, i think it depends on how you set this up on your server API, ResponseHandler or EntityUtils.toString will just give you all the data it will get in1 String. The easiest way to find out what your data looks like is to open URL in browser. You will get exactly the same output in your HttpGet response.

Comment: Yes, it is what I was refearing. If this Strings was a equivalent of all the data retrieve in my browser and how it was stored in the String.